# Load index.html or index.php in Apache based on condition

Tags: angular, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I want all requests that has the characters `wp-` as first path to load `index.php`. For any other request I want to load `index.html`.

If request goes to `https://example.com/wp-admin`, I want to load `index.php`

If request goes to `https://example.com/anything`, I want to load `index.html`

If request goes to `https://example.com/anything/wp-something`, I want to load `index.html`

The reason for this is that I'm serving a single page application (Angular) and WordPress on the same webserver. I want Angular to handle all routes except when there's `wp-` in the first path so that my editors can access the WordPress interface easily.

Is this possible?
Bad practice?
Better solutions?

Comment: A webserver can run multiple websites, e.g `example.com` and `wp-admin.example.com`, that might be cleaner solution.

Comment: Thanks, I added a subdomain, wp.example.com

Answer (score 0):

I actually do this with a plugin of mine, [Xo for Angular](https://wordpress.org/plugins/xo-for-angular/), which provides an integrated approach to loading an Angular App as a normal theme within WordPress.

Directing all front-end requests to a single template such as an Angular App is relatively easy by doing the following:

First you will need a php file, probably the index.php within your theme to include the contents of your Angular App.

```
// index.php
<?php
echo file_get_contents(get_template_directory() . '/dist/index.html');
```

Next you can place a filter such that regardless of the front-end path WordPress will instead render your index.php allowing the Angular App to take over.

```
// functions.php
<?php
add_filter('template_include', function() {
  return get_template_directory() . '/index.php';
}, 1, 0);
```

Hopefully that works!